# Extra fields added in registration form to be saved in wp_users table rather than wp_usermeta table (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have added extra fields in the Registration Form. The code is as follow:

```php
function wooc_extra_register_fields() {
       ?>
       <p class="form-row form-row-first">
       <label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <p class="form-row form-row-last">
       <label for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <div class="clear"></div>
       <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
       <label for="reg_billing_phone"><?php _e( 'Mobile Phone No.', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_phone'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'wooc_extra_register_fields' );
```

---

Now I want these fields to be visible in wp-user database so that all user data can be seen in a single place rather than switching to user meta data to see extra field data.
Is there any way?

In case I have to add an additional database then how to do?

Comment: please explain your requirement to keep the user detail to store in user table itself. Is it a 1-1 relationship?

Comment: Yes I want to keep the basic user data in user table itself. Like the first name, last name, email ID, mobile no, username and password. Currently the wp-user database only shows me user name, password and email ID (the basic fields of woocommerce)